# Можно ли вывести в Mysql связанные записи

Tags: mysql, выборка

Имеются 4 таблицы:

```
Vigruzka
User_Name0 Name0 DisplayName0 Publisher0 LastW
Anna.CM    Anna  Skype        Microsoft  2.0.9
...
rows 700

Users
Id_users User_Name0 Name0
1        Anna.CM    Anna
...
rows 3

Programs
Id_programs DisplayName0 Publisher0
1           Skype        Microsoft
...
rows 300

Updates
Id_updates id_Users Id_programs LastW
1          1        1           2.0.9
...
rows 300
```

Как вывести (сделать выборку) таблицу Updates чтобы она имела вид:

```
Updates
Id_updates id_Users Id_programs LastW
1          Anna.CM  Skype       2.0.9
...
rows 300
```

т.е чтобы за место цифр были связанные данные.

Таблицы связаны между собой

Выводить через команду `Select * from updates;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT upd.Id_updates, 
usr.User_Name0 as id_Users, 
prg.DisplayName0 as Id_programs, 
upd.LastW 
FROM Updates upd 
LEFT JOIN Users usr ON usr.Id_users = upd.id_Users 
LEFT JOIN Programs prg ON prg.Id_programs = upd.Id_programs
```

Comment: Спасибо, то что искал